# Convert base64 string to JPG

Tags: go

I am getting the **image as base64 string ( `dataurl` )**, Below is my function that converts the `dataurl` into the image,

Now if the image is png then png library will create the image and jpg library will throw an error and vice versa.

Problem is when i upload png it works well but when i **upload jpg file

 returns this error**

> **invalid JPEG format: missing SOI marker**

```
func (ProfileController) SetProfilePic(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    session, _ := session.UserSession.Get(r, "mvc-user-session")

    var fieldMapForBasic map[string]*json.RawMessage
    var f *os.File

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    json.Unmarshal(data, &fieldMapForBasic)

    image, _ := json.Marshal(fieldMapForBasic["image"])
    coI := strings.Index(string(image), ",")
    rawImage := string(image)[coI+1:]

    // Encoded Image DataUrl //
    unbased, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(rawImage))

    res := bytes.NewReader(unbased)
    path, _ := os.Getwd()

    // Path to store the image //
    newpath := filepath.Join(path +  "/storage",  strconv.Itoa(session.Values["id"].(int)))
    os.MkdirAll(newpath, os.ModePerm)
    uid := uuid.NewV4()
    fmt.Println(newpath)

    // if image is png this function will create the image from dataurl string //
    pngI, errPng := png.Decode(res)
    if errPng == nil {
        f, _ = os.OpenFile(newpath + "/" + uid.String() + ".png", os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREATE, 0777)
        png.Encode(f, pngI)
        fmt.Println("Png generated")
        user := model.User{}
        user.ProfilePic = "storage/" + strconv.Itoa(session.Values["id"].(int)) + "/" + uid.String()
        session.Values["profile_pic"] = user.ProfilePic
        session.Save(r, w)
        database.Connection.Id(session.Values["id"].(int)).Update(&user)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(errPng.Error())
    }

    // If image is Jpg this will generate the Image //
    jpgI, errJpg := jpeg.Decode(res)
    if errJpg == nil {
        f, _ = os.OpenFile(newpath + "/" + uid.String() + ".jpg", os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREATE, 0777)
        jpeg.Encode(f, jpgI, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 75})
        fmt.Println("Jpg created")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(errJpg.Error())
    }

    defer func() {
        f.Close()
    }()

    render.Json(w, "ok")
}
```

Input `dataurl` is:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
```

This might help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're passing your `io.Reader` to `png.Decode()`, which begins consuming the reader, only to discover that the input is not a valid PNG, so returns an error.

Then your partly-consumed reader is passed to `jpeg.Decode()`, which reads the data not yet read, which is not a valid JPEG, and returns the error you observe.

You need to create a new reader for each decoder:

```
pngI, errPng := png.Decode(bytes.NewReader(unbased))

// ...

jpgI, errJpg := jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(unbased))
```

Or better yet, consider the MIME type, and only call the proper decoder:

```
switch strings.TrimSuffix(image[5:coI], ";base64") {
case "image/png":
    pngI, err = png.Decode(res)
    // ...
case "image/jpeg":
    jpgI, err = jpeg.Decode(res)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked. But It will be appreciable if you can explain a little bit more. I am beginner in golang.

Comment: What do you want me to further explain?

Comment: " partly-consumed reader is passed to jpeg.Decode() " . I am not  able to understand this. I am passing the res that is same for both a new reader. isnt' it ?

Comment: In your version, `png.Decode` reads from the reader, consuming the data.  So by the time `jpeg.Decode` gets `res`, part of the data has already been consumed, so it no longer sees a complete JPEG file, but only the latter portion of a JPEG file.

Answer (score 8):

Here's something which may help, demonstrates quite a few other things too (you need to have two files: flower.jpg and mouse.png to make this work, available in the repository https://github.com/rravishankar/golangtraining/tree/master/test/jpegencode):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/jpeg"
    "image/png"
    "strings"

    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    createJpg()
    createPng()
    base64toPng()
    base64toJpg(getJPEGbase64("flower.jpg"))
}

//Take an existing jpg srcFileName and decode/encode it
func createJpg() {

    srcFileName := "flower.jpg"
    dstFileName := "newFlower.jpg"
    // Decode the JPEG data. If reading from file, create a reader with
    reader, err := os.Open(srcFileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer reader.Close()
    //Decode from reader to image format
    m, formatString, err := image.Decode(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Got format String", formatString)
    fmt.Println(m.Bounds())

    //Encode from image format to writer
    f, err := os.OpenFile(dstFileName, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    err = jpeg.Encode(f, m, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 75})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Jpg file", dstFileName, "created")

}

//Take an existing png srcFileName and decode/encode it
func createPng() {
    srcFileName := "mouse.png"
    dstFileName := "newMouse.png"
    reader, err := os.Open(srcFileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer reader.Close()
    //Decode from reader to image format
    m, formatString, err := image.Decode(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Got format String", formatString)
    fmt.Println(m.Bounds())

    //Encode from image format to writer
    f, err := os.OpenFile(dstFileName, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    err = png.Encode(f, m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Png file", dstFileName, "created")

}

//Converts pre-existing base64 data (found in example of https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode) to test.png
func base64toPng() {
    const data = `
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAHAAcAAD/2wBDABALDA4MChAODQ4SERATGCgaGBYWGDEjJR0oOjM9PDkzODdA
SFxOQERXRTc4UG1RV19iZ2hnPk1xeXBkeFxlZ2P/2wBDARESEhgVGC8aGi9jQjhCY2NjY2NjY2NjY2Nj
Y2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2P/wAARCABnAJYDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QA
HwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIh
MUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVW
V1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXG
x8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQF
BgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAV
YnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOE
hYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq
8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDlwKMD0pwzSiuK57QzGDxS7D6in8Y5ximnAPUfSlcq4m3ilUYp
2OKXHvRcVxnTtS7c07HNFK4DQPakC4PNOA+tOx70XAjK/So5gBGP94fzqfvUVx/qxx/EP51UXqRP4WSE
cmgjilP3jSEZqS0IO/NGDnpUiocDg/McDjvV6HTPOdVWYgsM5KcfzzQ2JySM2jp6VYu7SWzmMUwG4cgj
kMPUVBjjtTGtRu0Zopw+lFFxhinrGzuqqMsxAA9yaXFSRv5cqSEcIwYj6GpuZ30O30fSLKzhUpbpNMv3
5XGTn29BV28jt7pPLuIVljPBBFVreYx+VbqAjycgt3x14zRcNOxGyVFHQkIc/wA61exyKLbuzjdZ046d
ftEuTEw3Rk9SPT8P8Kpbea3tchbyVae4JkjbbGpGdwOM89Af6ViFTWUtGdcXoM2+woK1JtpNtTcoZt+l
Jt7ZqTbRtouFyPFRXI/c9D94fzqzioLsfuD/ALw/nVReqIn8LJCOTSY+tSMOTmkIpXLRu+F0t5pJxPHG
wjjUAuBjJJz1+laD6Pai+WaK9SBX6puzn6ZP+NV/Dkdtc6ZNbyAFwxLAHDYPv6VoQ21nPNEEiQGEFRtk
Gf0NaWTOeW7Of8QwGG4MRZnEbYXPJwRnOR0zWNXW+KrqBLUWi5EjbWCgcAA9c/gRXKYqZaGlK/LqMH0F
FLtHvRSNiYD2pSDTgpp6p0ywUHoTULXYxcktzrdCf7Xo8LP/AKyEmMNjJ46dfbFWJ5TDGNwB9lFUvDV9
YrbfYGbyrjcWG88S57g+vtV26ZIvMlumKwwjLZ6V0WfU54yTvYwtbubea2WNWbzg4bYQeBgj8OtYeKhj
u4y2HQxqxOD1xzxmrWAQCCGB6EGsaikndmsJxeiYzBo280/Z7UbayuaXGY5oIp+2lx9KLjIsVDeD/Rj/
ALy/zq1t96r3y4tT/vL/ADq4P3kRP4WSleTSFKkkKoCW4GaqNcMxIjXj1pxjKT0FKrGC1Nrw3vGrKkYz
5kTAr6455/HH510UdwPtRgWCbzF5+YYUf4Vwun39xpmoR3qASMmQUJwGU9Rnt/8AWrpbrxhb8/ZdOmaQ
gAGZwFH5ZJrpVKVlY5ZYhN6kXiu2eO/ikZlIljAAB5yM549OawSOOlPuLqe+umuLqTfM4OSOAo7ADsKh
hl/cRsTuJHPv7mlKi3sVTxNtGP20VJhThgSQaK52mnZnUqsWrpkyeUrr5pABOAPU1AGaXUCWJISHGPfP
P8qL7BiKnsMg46H3qrbzupbj5mPTPTpXVSglG551SpzSsXJ4/MBUgYIxyKpySyGBYJriV1D7kRpCVH4V
bSeNJ4xchni3DeqnBI+td7F4b0mKIRjT45VbktJlzk455+n6VtYzv2PNwFZWBHBGKVJDGVC54/nXQeMN
NttLNkba1jgWVWDmM8bhg4/nzXLSSbXVj6fyNKUdNRp21RtIRJGrjuM0u3FQ2DbodvcEkfQmrW2vLqLl
k0ejCXNFMj2/jQV9qkxSYNRcsZiq2oI32N2CkhWXJxwOe9XMcVt6hoPn6dFaW0wgRpNzvKDlz6+/0rai
ryv2Jm9LHJai+ZRGCBjnr71ErdAxAY9B611t1Y2cunbbaOQ3FvKZI3UqGlZMbiWwfcfhV231iwvLSM3U
lt5Uq52TuZG+hGMA12xXJGxxzjzybOQtNOvb5j9ktZJhnBIHyg+5PFX38JayqK/2eLJIBUTgkDA9q7ex
itrSHFpGsUbndhRgc+g7VNIyfZJAoJZUbb3I46CtFJMylBo8sdWhmYMuCnylc9wef5VUT7+1chc5NS7h
sUZO5RtIPUH3pkBDOxxxmqM9TQtn+WilhHfHaik43KTG3Z4IyPyrNVjGCsZ+dmwv6V3cXhSG8sYpJLud
JJIwxChdoJGcYx/Wkg8DafA4knvLiQr/ALqj+VQpKw3FtnFFfvbiSMgZJ6/jXp2n3d9cQRBTFsKD96EP
oOxPU/8A68VVtbbRtMVntbePKDLTSHJH/Aj/AEqHTvE66rq72VugMMcbSGTnL4wMAfjT5n0HyW3L+s6b
baxaJBdzN+7bcrxkAhun0rz3VNCv7e7lgigknWI43xLu6jjIHTjtXqfkpPGVYsBkghTikgsYIN/lhgXb
cxLkknp/ShczQ7xtY8vtEmhkj8yGRBuCnehUcnHcVtmwfJ/fQ8e7f/E12txZW91C0U6b42xlST2OR/Ko
Bo1gM/uW55/1jf41nOipu7LhV5FZHIGzI6zwj/vr/Ck+yr3uYf8Ax7/CutbQdMb71tn/ALaN/jSf8I/p
X/PoP++2/wAan6rAr6wzkWt0II+1Rc/7Lf4Vd1eeCSKBbdZDdShYoiZNoyfY10P/AAj2lf8APmP++2/x
oPh/SjKspsozIuNrZORjp3qo0FHYPb3OZt7ae3SzjuItsiRSAgnccl/UA+3Q1yNjKLR4ZZYY5VD7tkv3
WwO/+e1evPp9nI257aJm6bioz1z1+tY+s6Hplnot9PbWMMcqwOFcLyOO1bJWMZSTOPHi+9w3mosrlyd2
9lCj02g9P/1e9a3hzxAbl2ikZRcdQueHHt7j864Y8Z4I4oRzG6urFWU5BHBB7HNJxTFGbR6he6Vpmtgm
eLy5zwZI/lb8fX8azIvBUUTHdfSFP4QsYB/HNZ+k+KEnRY75hHOvAk6K/v7H9K6yyvlnQBmDZ6GsnzR0
N0oy1RzOtaN/Y1tHNFO06u+zYy4I4Jzx9KKveJblXuordSGES5b6n/62PzorKVdp2LjQTVyWz8UWEWlq
jSgyxfJt6EgdDzWTdeLIZGO7zHI/hVajGmWWP+PWL8qwlAIURrhpMAHHJA71pRcZrToZzcoEuo6heakA
GHk245CZ6/X1qPTLq40q+W5t2QybSpDAkEEc55/zilk5k2r91eKhLDzWz2rpsczbbuemeD76fUNG865I
MiysmQMZAAwa3a5j4ftu0ByP+fh/5CulkLLG7INzhSVHqe1Fh3uOoqn9qQQxyhndmHIxwOmSR2xQ13KD
KoiBZOV9JBnt707MVy5RWdNdy7wRGf3bfMinnO1jg+vY03WXLaJO3mhQ20b0zwpYf0qlG7S7icrJs08U
VwumgC+YiQyeVtZH567hzj8aSL949oGhE/2v5pJCDkksQwBHC4/+vXQ8LZ2uYxxCavY7us/xCcaBfn0h
b+VP0bnSrb94ZMJgOecj1rl/GfidUE2k2gy5+SeQjgA/wj3rlas2jdao48qrjLAGkSKPk4Gc1WMj92I+
lIJnU8OfxPWo5inBokmtQTmM4OOh71b0q6vbFmWCbaxHyqQGAP0PT8KhSTzVyo5ocSKA5VfTOTmqsmRd
pl99XjPzThzK3zOeOSeveirNmkgg/fIpYsTkYORxRXmzlTjJqx6EVUcU7mhkKCzdAK59QI9zYxtG1fYU
UVtgtmY4nZEa8Ak9aqFv3rfSiiu1nMeifDv/AJF+T/r4f+QrqqKKQwzQenNFFMCOKFIgNuThdoJ5OPSk
ubeK6t3gnXdG4wwziiii/UTKMOg6dbzJLFE4dSCP3rEdeOM8805tDsGMvySgSsS6rM6gk9eAcUUVftZt
3uyVGNthuq3Eei6DK8H7sRR7YuMgHtXkc8rzTNLM26RyWY+p70UVnLY0iEsUipG7rhZBlDkc1HgYoorM
0HwyBXGeRjmrcUhMg2ghezd//rUUVcTKW5s2jZtY/QDaOKKKK8ip8bPRj8KP/9k=
`

    reader := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(data))
    m, formatString, err := image.Decode(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bounds := m.Bounds()
    fmt.Println(bounds, formatString)

    //Encode from image format to writer
    pngFilename := "test.png"
    f, err := os.OpenFile(pngFilename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    err = png.Encode(f, m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Png file", pngFilename, "created")

}

//Given a base64 string of a JPEG, encodes it into an JPEG image test.jpg
func base64toJpg(data string) {

    reader := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(data))
    m, formatString, err := image.Decode(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bounds := m.Bounds()
    fmt.Println("base64toJpg", bounds, formatString)

    //Encode from image format to writer
    pngFilename := "test.jpg"
    f, err := os.OpenFile(pngFilename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    err = jpeg.Encode(f, m, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 75})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Jpg file", pngFilename, "created")

}

//Gets base64 string of an existing JPEG file
func getJPEGbase64(fileName string) string {

    imgFile, err := os.Open(fileName)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer imgFile.Close()

    // create a new buffer base on file size
    fInfo, _ := imgFile.Stat()
    var size = fInfo.Size()
    buf := make([]byte, size)

    // read file content into buffer
    fReader := bufio.NewReader(imgFile)
    fReader.Read(buf)

    imgBase64Str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buf)
    //fmt.Println("Base64 string is:", imgBase64Str)
    return imgBase64Str

}
```

You may also want to read the example in https://golang.org/pkg/image/#Decode
Hope this helps.

Comment: this is my input string for the Jpg

Comment: If SOI marker is missing, then some bytes may be missing in your base64 string (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) Modify your program to print the base64 string for the JPEG. And then run my program (demonstrated to work) separately with your JPEG's base64 string as input (to the `base64toJpg` function) - see if you get the JPEG back. If you get an error, see what it is and if required get the source JPEG, use the `getJPEGbase64` function from the above code to get the base64 string for it, and match the base64 string you get in the http request.

Comment: i have tested the base64 string online https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter . It works fine

Comment: Can you please try as suggested and see what's happening? Your message says that SOI marker is missing, so chances are it might be!

Comment: my problem is that i have to send the image via ajax as base64 data-url and have to make jpg from it.I am able to get string what you have written in base64toPng()   "data const" string using the string functions and encoding image using it make the png but not jpg.

Comment: For a given JPEG file, receive it via your program, dump base64 string and also get the base64 for the same JPEG from the above code - compare!

Comment: what i need is convert the data-url shown in the question into the jpg again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153685/discussion-between-mchampaneri-and-ravi).

Comment: Can you please follow what has been recommended?

Comment: It works with your dataurl too (using the code above). If you have compared the string outputs, you would have probably found this by now. The JPEG data to be sent for decoding is however after the header "data:image/jpeg;base64," in your string.

Comment: Use the code I have shared above, strip the header from your data and you are good! One gets the `missing SOI error` as it's not finding the signature bytes. At least the problem you have mentioned seems resolved.