# base64 string to jpg file object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, base64, jpeg, base64url

I'd like to convert a base64 string into a jpg file object using JavaScript.

I have tried the following (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022262/covert-base64-string-to-jpg) thread), but it's returning me a corrupted file when I attempt to download the jpg image:

```
this.urltoFile(screenshot, 'file.jpg', "image/jpeg")

urltoFile(url, filename, mimeType){
   return (fetch(url)
       .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
       .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], filename, {type:mimeType});})
   );
}
```

I've also tried the following threads but none of them give me a valid JavaScript File object, and if they do the resulting file is corrupt:

[Covert base64 string to JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022262/covert-base64-string-to-jpg)

[Convert Base64 to image file with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631629/convert-base64-to-image-file-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert base64 to image in javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery)